# Как исправить неправильный подсчёт копеек?

Tags: python

Моя проблема в том, что не правильно подсчитаны копейки в раздели накопления, так как я не понимаю как реализовать это условие в задаче:

> Сумма доходов равна 50 001.25 , 10 % от этой суммы это 5000.125 рублей. Пол копейки как валюты не существует, поэтому эта половинка переходит в накопления."

Вот вся задача, свой код прикреплю ниже:

Семья решила заняться оптимизацией своих денежных расходов и придумала следующую схему:

```
10 % доходов идут на отпуск
30 % доходов на пропитание и еду
5 % на коммунальные платежи
15 % на выходной досуг
остальные 40% идут в накопления
```

Если вдруг нужный процент не получается сделать, тогда копейка перекидывается в накопления. Например:

Сумма доходов равна `50 001.25`, `10 %` от этой суммы это `5000.125` рублей. Пол копейки как валюты не существует, поэтому эта половинка переходит в накопления.

Напишите для семьи программу, которая будет принимать на вход месячный доход мужа и жены и рассчитывать сколько им нужно отложить на каждую категорию.

Ваша программа принимает два числа типа `float`. Целая часть – рубли, а дробная – копейки.

В качестве результата работы выведите количество рублей и копеек для каждой из категорий в таком формате:

```
Отпуск: 10 руб. 5 коп.
Пропитание и еда: 30 руб. 15 коп.
Коммунальные платежи: 5 руб. 0 коп.
Досуг: 10 руб. 11 коп.
Накопления: 50 руб. 3 коп.
```

Мой код:

```
mather = float(input())
dad = float(input())

income = mather + dad

#Отпуск 10%
otp = income * 0.10
rubOtp = int(otp)
kopOtp = int((100*(otp-rubOtp))% 100)

#Пропитание и еда 30%
eda = income * 0.30
rubEda = int(eda)
kopEda = int((100*(eda-rubEda))%100)

#Комунальные услуги 5%
kom = income * 0.05
rubKom = int(kom)
kopKom = int((100*(kom-rubKom))%100)

#Досуг 15%
dos = income * 0.15
rubDos = int(dos)
kopDos = int((100*(dos-rubDos))%100)

#Накопление 40%
nak = income  * 0.40
rubNak = int(nak)
kopNak = int((100*(nak-rubNak))%100)

print("Отпуск:", rubOtp,'руб.', kopOtp,'коп.')
print("Пропитание и еда:", rubEda,'руб.', kopEda,'коп.')
print("Коммунальные платежи:", rubKom,'руб.', kopKom,'коп.')
print("Досуг:", rubDos,'руб.', kopDos,'коп.')
print("Накопления:", rubNak,'руб.', kopNak,'коп.')
```

Задания:

```
Sample Input 1:

30000.50
20000.75
Sample Output 1:

Отпуск: 5000 руб. 12 коп.
Пропитание и еда: 15000 руб. 37 коп.
Коммунальные платежи: 2500 руб. 6 коп.
Досуг: 7500 руб. 18 коп.
Накопления: 20000 руб. 52 коп.
Sample Input 2:

123.45
24.56
Sample Output 2:

Отпуск: 14 руб. 80 коп.
Пропитание и еда: 44 руб. 40 коп.
Коммунальные платежи: 7 руб. 40 коп.
Досуг: 22 руб. 20 коп.
Накопления: 59 руб. 21 коп.
Sample Input 3:

123
234
Sample Output 3:

Отпуск: 35 руб. 70 коп.
Пропитание и еда: 107 руб. 10 коп.
Коммунальные платежи: 17 руб. 85 коп.
Досуг: 53 руб. 55 коп.
Накопления: 142 руб. 80 коп.
Sample Input 4:

100
200
Sample Output 4:

Отпуск: 30 руб. 0 коп.
Пропитание и еда: 90 руб. 0 коп.
Коммунальные платежи: 15 руб. 0 коп.
Досуг: 45 руб. 0 коп.
Накопления: 120 руб. 0 коп.
Sample Input 5:

30000.55
20000.75
Sample Output 5:

Отпуск: 5000 руб. 13 коп.
Пропитание и еда: 15000 руб. 39 коп.
Коммунальные платежи: 2500 руб. 6 коп.
Досуг: 7500 руб. 19 коп.
Накопления: 20000 руб. 53 коп.
Sample Input 6:

32344.45
34543.23
Sample Output 6:

Отпуск: 6688 руб. 76 коп.
Пропитание и еда: 20066 руб. 30 коп.
Коммунальные платежи: 3344 руб. 38 коп.
Досуг: 10033 руб. 15 коп.
Накопления: 26755 руб. 9 коп.
Sample Input 7:

30000.55
20000.85
Sample Output 7:

Отпуск: 5000 руб. 14 коп.
Пропитание и еда: 15000 руб. 42 коп.
Коммунальные платежи: 2500 руб. 7 коп.
Досуг: 7500 руб. 21 коп.
Накопления: 20000 руб. 56 коп.
```

Comment: Откажитесь от вещественных чисел. Считайте всё в целых копейках.

Comment: Можете ли вы к вопросу добавить набор тестов?

Comment: @Acinit добавил, извините, что только сейчас

Comment: Можно использовать модуль decimal: https://docs.python.org/3/library/decimal.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Вещественные числа не годятся для того чтобы точно представлять десятичные дроби:

> ```
> @>>> 0.3
> 0.3
> @>>> f'{0.3:.20f}'
> '0.29999999999999998890'
> ```

Десятичная дробь *0.3* внутри компьютера хранится в виде очень близкого но другого числа. Сосчитаем налог 30% от 101 рубля. Должно получиться 30 рублей 30 копеек. А на деле немного меньше:

> ```
> @>>> 101 * 0.3
> 30.299999999999997
> ```

Вычитаем целые рубли и умножаем на *100* чтобы перевести число в копейки:

> ```
> @>>> 100 * (101 * 0.3 - 30)
> 29.999999999999716
> ```

Получилось немного меньше 30 копеек, как должно бы быть. Сейчас произойдет катастрофа - небольшая ошибка приведёт к потере копейки:

> ```
> @>>> int(100 * (101 * 0.3 - 30))
> 29
> ```

Вещественные числа придуманы для инженерных расчётов. При их проектировании ставились две цели - точность и быстрота. И они действительно точные и быстрые. То что *0.3* нельзя записать в виде компьютерного числа - не важно. Его можно представить с огромной точностью - а это и нужно для инженерных расчётов. И совсем не годится для бухгалтерии.

Можно аккуратно подправить вычисления так чтобы вычисления стали верными. Но это сложный путь - надо будет доказывать что учтены все возможные ошибки представления для исходных чисел и все ошибки округления для операций. Есть решение проще: использовать точные целые копейки вместо приближенных вещественных рублей.

Сразу нарушу собственное правило: для простоты чтения вещественные рубли всё-таки будут использованы. Но они сразу же переводятся в копейки. Это решение будет ошибаться, но только для очень больших, астрономических, сумм:

```
def get_money(s):
    return int(round(100 * float(s)))
```

Проценты тоже будут хранится как целые числа. Для получения процента от суммы сумма и процент перемножаются и делятся на сто. Результат округляется вниз к целому:

```
def get_percent(money, percent):
    return money * percent // 100
```

Основной код читает доходы, складывает их, вычисляет проценты - всё в целых копейках. Из-за округления вниз сумма расходов может быть меньше суммы дохода. Ошибка `income - sum(expenses)` добавляется к последнему расходу в списке:

```
def main():
    percents = (
        ('Отпуск'              , 10),
        ('Пропитание и еда'    , 30),
        ('Коммунальные платежи',  5),
        ('Досуг'               , 15),
        ('Накопления'          , 40)
    )

    income = get_money(input()) + get_money(input())
    expenses = [get_percent(income, p[1]) for p in percents]

    expenses[-1] += income - sum(expenses)

    assert sum(expenses) == income

    for (w, _), e in zip(percents, expenses): 
        print(f'{w}: {e // 100} руб. {e % 100} коп.')


main()
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Для операций с деньгами можно использовать класс `Decimal` из стандартного модуля [decimal](https://docs.python.org/3/library/decimal.html).

   Все операции с ним примерно как с float (кроме создания объекта), но его преимущество в том, что он хранит число именно так как мы его видим в десятичном формате, никаких неожиданностей типа `0.1 + 0.2 != 0.3`.

   Из особенностей - при операциях с объектами `Decimal` (типа сложения/вычитания/умножения/деления) нельзя использовать `Decimal` и `float` вместе, можно использовать `int` или другой `Decimal`. Например, `Decimal("1000.0") * 0.15` не будет работать, вместо этого нужно писать `Decimal("1000.0") * Decimal("0.15")` или `Decimal("1000.0") * 15 / 100`.

   Но в целом `Decimal` работает, конечно, медленнее чем `float` (просто из-за того что это более сложный формат, сам модуль `decimal` при этом [реализован на Си](https://github.com/python/cpython/tree/main/Modules/_decimal)).
2. Чтобы дробную часть превратить в копейки, нужно просто умножить на 100 и привести к целому, т.е. вместо `kopOtp = int((100*(otp-rubOtp))% 100)` пишите `kopOtp = int((otp - rubOtp) * 100)`
3. Чтобы все дробные копейки переходили в накопления, а не терялись, накопления нужно считать не через процент, а из общей суммы доходов вычесть все расходы

```
from decimal import Decimal

# mather = Decimal(input())
# dad = Decimal(input())

# income = mather + dad
income = Decimal("50001.25")

#Отпуск 10%
otp = income * 10 / 100
# .quantize(Decimal(".01")) округляет результат до .01 (т.е. до 1 копейки в нашем случае)
otp = otp.quantize(Decimal(".01"))  
rubOtp = int(otp)
kopOtp = int((otp - rubOtp) * 100)

#Пропитание и еда 30%
eda = income * 30 / 100
eda = eda.quantize(Decimal(".01"))  
rubEda = int(eda)
kopEda = int((eda - rubEda) * 100)

#Комунальные услуги 5%
kom = income * 5 / 100
kom = kom.quantize(Decimal(".01"))
rubKom = int(kom)
kopKom = int((kom - rubKom) * 100)

#Досуг 15%
dos = income * 15 / 100
dos = dos.quantize(Decimal(".01"))
rubDos = int(dos)
kopDos = int((dos - rubDos) * 100)

#Все остальное идет в накопление
nak = income - otp - eda - kom - dos
nak = nak.quantize(Decimal(".01"))
rubNak = int(nak)
kopNak = int((nak - rubNak) * 100)

print("Отпуск:", rubOtp,'руб.', kopOtp,'коп.')
print("Пропитание и еда:", rubEda,'руб.', kopEda,'коп.')
print("Коммунальные платежи:", rubKom,'руб.', kopKom,'коп.')
print("Досуг:", rubDos,'руб.', kopDos,'коп.')
print("Накопления:", rubNak,'руб.', kopNak,'коп.')
```

Вывод:

```
Отпуск: 5000 руб. 12 коп.
Пропитание и еда: 15000 руб. 38 коп.
Коммунальные платежи: 2500 руб. 6 коп.
Досуг: 7500 руб. 19 коп.
Накопления: 20000 руб. 50 коп.
```